# TSeD Mixed type Enum and Collection

Tags: typescript, validation, enums

I am using TSeD version `6.38.1`
I have the following model.

```
import {Any, CollectionOf, Enum, Property} from "@tsed/schema";
export enum Status {
   status1,
   status2,
   ...
}

export class FilterParams {
  ... Some other fields

  @Any(Enum(Status), CollectionOf(Enum(Status)))
  status: Status[] | Status
}
```

I struggling to annotate `status` field of `FilterParams`. I want it to be a `Status` or an array of `Status`

I have tried the following annotations but none of them worked.

1. `@Enum(Status) status: Status[] | Status`: This only accept accepts a single `Status` but rejects the array of `Status`
2. `@Enum(Status) status: Status`: This also only accept accepts a single `Status` but rejects the array of `Status`
3. `@Enum(Status) status: Status[]`: This only accept accepts list of `Status` but rejects the array of `Status`
4. `@Any(Enum(Status), CollectionOf(Enum(Status))) status: Status[] | Status`: This gives `AJV_VALIDATION_ERROR` on runtime with message `FilterParams.status.0 should be object.`

What to achieve this validation in TSeD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that with decorators (and mix decorators like you shown in the example is not possible).

The solution is to use the function API to describe correctly the schema and use OnDeserialize decorator to be ensure that you will have always an array of Status.

```
import {Any, CollectionOf, Enum, Property, string, array} from "@tsed/schema";
import {OnDeseriliaze} from "json-mapper";
export enum Status {
   status1,
   status2,
   ...
}
const StatusSchema = string().enum(Status)

export class FilterParams {
  ... Some other fields

  @AnyOf(StatusSchema, array().items(StatusSchema))
  @OnDeseriliaze(o => [].concat(o))
  status: Status[];
}
```

See you
Romain